# Is the informational approach to thermodynamics generally accepted as "correct"?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, information, models

This question is about the "ontology" as it were of statistical mechanics. In my limited reading of (equilibrium) statistical mechanics texts, I have encountered two viewpoints for what is "going on". I restrict to isolated systems, since all other cases derive therefrom.

(1) The first is encountered in texts like Reif and Callen (2nd edition), wherein it is emphasized over and over that macroscopic systems undergo rapid transitions between all accessible states (with some appropriate probability distribution). It follows (they postulate), that anything we can *observe* macroscopically about properties in these systems involves a suitable average over the corresponding property value in each of the accessible states.

(2) The second is encountered in texts like Rau and Balian, but I believe both of these are derived from the work of Jaynes -- it is an "information theoretic" approach, wherein we say that the correct assignment of system state is the one which maximizes the entropy of the system given certain data/constraints. With the system state so specified, the laws of the quantum mechanics of mixed states take over for anything we want to know.

These viewpoints seem to me to be at odds or, at the very least, not saying the same thing. In (1), there is an explicit ontology -- that the system is continuously transitioning -- and in the second we (appropriately) throw our hands up and say "we don't know what's going on but, being good Bayesians, we'll follow this rule which is the 'correct' one for assigning a system state given the uncertainty".

My questions are:

(A) Are these approaches indeed at odds?

(B) Is there a generally accepted framework for (equilibrium) statistical mechanics? I ask in the spirit of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/748060/is-rigged-hilbert-space-generally-considered-the-correct-structure-for-qm) question.